# Jagged array with two 2d array

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

How to create a jagged array that consists of two 2d array? please help. Thank you.

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[3][];
```

the above code creates a single-dimensional array that has three elements, each of which is a single-dimensional array of integers. Can any one help me in creating a two 2d array.

Comment: what do you mean, that every item in the jagged array is instantiated to the same dimension?

Comment: i want the the 2d array with the different row length. Is it possible?

Comment: do you mean a "2d Multi-Dimensional Array" or a "2 Dimensional Jagged Array" or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this,

```
var jaggedArray = new[]
        {
            new[] { 1 },
            new[] { 1, 2 ,3 },
            new[] { 1, 2 }
        };
```

this creates a "jagged" array, with two dimensions where each "row" has a different length.

All of the following assertions would be `True`.

```
jaggedArray.Length == 3
jaggedArray[0].Length == 1
jaggedArray[1].Length == 3
jaggedArray[2].Length == 2
```

---

If you knew the lengths were fixed but, didn't know the data, you could do,

```
var jaggedArray = new[] { new int[1], new int[3], new int[2] };
```

---

Following on from you comment, maybe you want something like this,

```
var jaggedArray1 = new[]
        {
            new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
            new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
            new[] { 1, 2 }
        };

var jaggedArray2 = new[]
        {
            new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
            new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
        };

int[][][] jaggedArray = new[]
        {
            jaggedArray1,
            jaggedArray2
        };
```

you could just do,

```
var jaggedArray = new[]
        {
            new[]
                {
                    new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
                    new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
                    new[] { 1, 2 }
                },

            new[]
                {
                    new[] { 1, 2, 3 },
                    new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
                }
        };
```

Comment: Yes i want some thing like this. Can i implement in this way?
    `var jaggedArray1 = new[]
        {
            new[] { 1,2,3,4},
            new[] { 1, 2 ,3 },
            new[] { 1, 2 }
        };
            var jaggedArray2 = new[]
        {
            new[] { 1,2,3},
            new[] { 1, 2 ,3,4 },
           
        };
            int[] jaggedArray = new int[2][];
            jaggedArray[0] = jaggedArray1;
            jaggedArray[1] = jaggedArray2;`

Comment: @UditSaikia looks syntactically correct but, its hard to tell in a comment.

Comment: it gives an error
    Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[][]' to 'int[]'

Comment: @UditSaikia, now that I've added your comment to my question, that makes sense, see the edit.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
int[][,] jaggedArray = new int[3][,];
```

The `,` creates the 2D array in the jagged array. Read more on Multi-dimensional arrays on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx).

Next, you have to initialize every 2D array inside that array:

```
int[,] 2dArray1 = new int[2,3];
jaggedArray[0] = 2dArray1;

int[,] 2dArray2 = new int[4,5];
jaggedArray[1] = 2dArray2;
```

And so on.

Comment: but why would you do that, instead of `int[3][][]`

Comment: @Jodrell: That is a jagged array, not a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: Can the row size be of different length?

Comment: Sure, it's your party.

Comment: @UditSaikia of course, in both a 3 dimensional jagged array and a collection of multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @Jodrell: It's a one-dimensional array with three items, which contains of a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Is it possible that the 2-D array can contain 3 rows having length of 4, 3 and 2 respectively

Comment: @UditSaikia: It's unclear what you want to achieve. 2D arrays don't have rows, they have axis.

Comment: I have got this question that I am also not clear about "Create a Jagged array of integers. This array should consists of two 2-D arrays, First 2-D array should contain 3 rows having length of 4, 3 and 2 respectively. Second 2-D array should contain 2 rows with length 3 and 4 respectively"

Comment: So you want two arrays? Take a look at Jodrells answer. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

The second pair of brackets indicates the dimensions. So it's like you are declaring a multi-dimensional array except you don't need to specify dimensions in the definition.You can initialize each array with different dimensions.

```
int[][,] jaggedArray = new int[3][,];
```

Comment: but why would you do that, instead of `int[3][][]`